# Refused entry into Ireland

Tags: customs-and-immigration, ireland, serial-refusals

I need advice from someone that knows more or less how immigration works in Ireland  because I've been refused twice entry into Ireland but from my destination not at the aiport of Ireland.

The first time refusal was I never had enough documentation which I understood and the second time it was too little documentation to support my stay.

So I will be trying the third time but this time I will get everything in order but I want to know is my data or info  on Ireland immigration system if they put my passport number in? And with this third time with all my proper docs, is the a chance of succeeding or will they just deny my due to last 2 times I tried?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. You're going to do need to provide a lot more info: what is your nationality and do you have a valid visa for Ireland?  Why is the airline refusing to board you?  (This is *very* different from Immigration denying you entry.)

Comment: On what basis were you intending to travel to Ireland? https://www.irishimmigration.ie/?

Comment: And you mean you were refused at your originating airport or via the consulate in the country where you applied, not your destination, correct? Your destination would be immigration at an Irish airport or port.

Comment: From the limited information you have provided it sounds like you were denied boarding by the airline because they did not consider you had a valid travel document or a visa (if you are from a country that requires visas for Ireland).
Airlines face a fine if they carry incorrectly documented passengers to Ireland. (Many countries have similar laws).

The proper route for clarifying things is surely to contact the nearest Irish Embassy or Consulate to establish whether the documents you have meet their entry requirements.

Comment: The very first thing we need to know is your citizenship. Then if you were refused while applying for a visa, or at the airport. My guess is that you were refused a visa. Then what documents they said were missing and further details (if you can add the refusal letter which your personal details blacked out that would help). What type of visa did you request? What was your purpose of travel? Did you have a return ticket? What is your situation at home (studying, employed, self-employed, married, kids, property…)? But yes, they will know you already had 2 refusals which makes things harder.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know when these refusals happened. If fairly recently and your personal circumstances are pretty much unchanged since, it’s probably a waste of time and money to reapply.  But if the refusals were some time ago and/or your circumstances have changed a lot since, a denial isn’t necessarily automatic on a fresh application.

Answer (score 2):

It’s hard to guess from your question, but my impression is that you applied for a visa (twice) and were rejected (twice), and now you want to apply again for a visa.

Will they know you already applied and were refused a visa? Most certainly. And not only via your passport number (it would be to easy to suddenly “lose” your passport, get a new one, and start anew). They can use your name, date of birth and other details to get the same result. If you got to the stage where they took biometrics (fingerprints…) it’s even easier and more foolproof for them.

The only case where it could be “forgotten” is if the applications were long enough ago (at least 5 years I think, but that may vary).

Will they automatically reject a new application because the two previous ones were? No. But they will start with a pretty negative opinion, and will start looking for any possible reason to do so. So your application must be bulletproof. If your circumstances did not change much since last time, don’t waste your time and money applying again.

Remember that a visa is not a right. It’s not a matter of filling the right form with the right info and providing the requested documentation and you get approved. No. It’s more like applying for a job, or a spot in a sought after university, or seducing someone. You must prove to them you are the person they want.

Each country decides who they want to let in or not. For visitor visas, ideally they want people who will come and spend a lot of money or somehow generate money, but in any case they want to be sure you will be leaving in time, not overstay, not try to live in the country, not work in the country, not be a burden on the state, etc.

So you have to **convince** them that you have a valid reason to come, that you can afford it, and most importantly that you will go back home. This usually means having a good, stable, well paid job (ideally by their standards, not those of your country), or being enrolled in a course of studies, or having a pile of cash you can live on, and/or having family to take care of (though this can backfire), and/or having a place to stay, ideally owning property.

If you can’t do that, don’t bother applying, and wait until your situation changes favourably before you do. The more bad applications, the greater the chances they will just think “oh yet another bogus application from maidils, quick, let’s find any reason to reject it”.